# Where to add application name for Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, .net-4.8

Visual Studio 2022 with all updates and running on .Net Framework (not Core)

I would like to use Application Insights so when my app raises any relevant errors/events it is recorded to AppInsights.

I started with this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net and created two different application along with having events being recorded which i can see in Azure App Insights.

When i view the data it has the same AppID for two applications i created. I cant find any document to suggest where i could change the appId or any other way to state the source of the event if from application one or application two.

After viewing the reports and documentation im not sure if i need to configure Azure App Insights differently or if i could change it at app level? I just want to be able to record any errors but also have a way to determine which application the error was raised from?

Edit

I have added the below class

```
public class ReportInitialise : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialise(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "Test";
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = "TestInstance";
    }
}
```

Edit 2

In the MvcApplication class i added the below to `Application_Start`

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new ReportInitialise );
```

which resolved the last part of the puzzle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When i view the data it has the same AppID for two applications i created.

That is correct. It is the ID of the Application Insights resource.

> After viewing the reports and documentation im not sure if i need to configure Azure App Insights differently or if i could change it at app level? I just want to be able to record any errors but also have a way to determine which application the error was raised from?

Typically this is done by inspecting the `cloud_RoleName` property. In Web Apps afaik this is set to the web app name. You can override it using a telemetry initializer if you want.

Comment: Correct. Many apps can send data to the same Application Insights resource. In this case they can be differentiated by cloud_RoleName. It is also possible to have an Application Insights resource per app as well.

Comment: Not sure what im missing. Ive added some new code under Edit within my original thread. Is this along the correct lines?

Comment: If it is not already populated out of the box the code you show will do the job. Do not forget to add the telemetry to the configuration.

Comment: When you say configuration, where about would that be as at present i have that in the MvcApplicaton class but i dont believe it was already populated unless i missed it?